# Fixing js "Script error"

Tags: javascript, webpack-dev-server

I'm having difficulties implementing something simple: I have an index.html file served on http://localhost:3200 by ruby on rails, which uses a javascript file served on http://localhost:8000 by webpack-dev-server.

So here's what I have:

```
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="http://localhost:8000/app.js" />
  </head>
  <!-- ... -->
</html>
```

My app.js file is sent with, amongst others, the following header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

What I want is to be able to override `window.onerror` in **app.js**, and see caught errors, rather than "Script error".

What am I missing?

-- edit --
Since it might not be clear enough: my script does load. I have no problem with that. My issue is that I need to report errors that happen to somewhere else, but I can't do that since any error that occurs in app.js is reported as "Script error" rather than something more explicit.

Comment: There's no need for CORS headers when loading scripts.

Comment: Remove the `crossorigin` property in the `script` tag. By default scripts don't have single origin restriction. The `crossorigin` property was added to enable people to enforce CORS restriction. So unless you want to block script loading form foreign urls you should remove `crossorigin` property form the script tag.

Comment: I'm just trying to fix an issue following what I can see everywhere, like on this page: https://raygun.com/blog/2015/05/fixing-script-errors/. Removing the `crossorigin` attribute doesn't solve my problem either, unfortunately.

Comment: So redefine window.onerror....

Comment: Well webpack puts all of the scripts into one file. And you do not like the fact it points to that file?

Comment: So, are you looking to just report an error (to somewhere) when it occurs in app.js when that script executes? As long as the script downloads and is otherwise valid (no syntax problems or stackoverflows etc), wouldn't a try/catch, or some other kind of guard, do it?

Comment: Yeah. I need to send a description of any error that occurs in my script to a third-party service. The problem is, right now, all I send is "Script error" which isn't really helpful.

Comment: What is the window.onerror code you are using to send to the server?

Comment: I'd catch the error, and if all you get is "Script Error", create something that makes sense based on what you see, and send that instead. That's a really common practice, reported errors don't always make sense and/or aren't always useful (e.g. angular's "everything is a promise error"). Note also you might want to capture the stack from the caught error if that makes sense, and parse out whatever you may find that seems to be useful, and send that along with your "human readable" description.

Comment: My problem is that I really have NO clue about the occuring error. I can't even try to guess where and why it happened. It could be caused by a typo in a var, a foo.bar call where foo is null, etc.

Comment: Then you've got to grab that script, put it in a little sandbox, and base case it. Run it locally and/or get the tests for it (or write the tests yourself) and run it. You should then find what you need easily enough. You might even just see the error in your IDE with a red squiggle.

Comment: Does webpack compile correct you code? Maybe error into you js code?

Comment: That's a useful comment (the webpack compile), but say the script uses bracket notation on a non-existent property, you wouldn't catch that during compile time (and any number of other things that easily beat compiler checks). I've heard, "yeah but it compiles", but still gotten runtime errors, so many times that the whole notion of compile-time catching seems overstated to me. It's a good indicator of code health but certainly not a final answer, it's more along the lines of, "it will probably run. But not definitely."

Comment: Having the same problem. Not sure what went wrong. The cors header are set correctly but I still got script error instead of actual error. Wonder if it is solved for you.

Answer (score 8):

What sourcemap (devtool) are you using?

I was getting this issue, and it changing from `eval-source-map` to `source-map` fixed it.

Comment: fixed it for me as well!

Comment: Strange I got it fixed by applying this change too. But I don't know the rationale behind this.

Comment: I should have known from the beginning to include the term 'webpack' in my search for 'script error'.  This answer worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This is a google chrome issue, should be when Chrome 71 is released.

Here are the relevant issue threads:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=765909
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5681

Edit: This also impacts electron users.